# Relationship extraction between person and city/state

Tags: nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction, spacy

I'm trying to take a sentence and extract the relationship between Person(PER) and Place(GPE).

**Sentence**: "John is from Ohio, Michael is from Florida and Rebecca is from Nashville which is in Tennessee."

For the final person, she has both a city and a state that could get extracted as her place.  So far, I've tried using nltk to do this, but have only been able to extract her city and not her state.

What I've tried:

```
import re
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.sem.relextract import extract_rels, rtuple

sentence = "John is from Ohio, Michael is from Florida and Rebecca is from Nashville which is in Tennessee."
chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
ISFROM = re.compile(r'.*\bfrom\b.*')
rels = extract_rels('PER', 'GPE', chunked, corpus = 'ace', pattern = ISFROM)
for rel in rels:
    print(rtuple(rel))
```

My output is:

```
[PER: 'John/NNP'] 'is/VBZ from/IN' [GPE: 'Ohio/NNP']
[PER: 'Michael/NNP'] 'is/VBZ from/IN' [GPE: 'Florida/NNP']
[PER: 'Rebecca/NNP'] 'is/VBZ from/IN' [GPE: 'Nashville/NNP']
```

The problem is Rebecca.  How can I extract that both Nashville and Tennesee are part of her location?  Or even just Tennessee alone?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have to first extract intra-location relationship (Nashville in Tennessee). Then ensure that you transitively assign all locations to Rebecca (if Rebecca is in Nashville and Nashville is in Tennessee then Rebecca is in Nashville and Rebecca is in Tennessee).

That would be one more relationship type and some logic for the above inference (things get complicated pretty quickly but it is hard to avoid it).